# ImageButton on Fragment which goes to another Activity. Android Studio

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

I have been searching this but I haven't found anything that could help me.
I have a main activity with 2 fragments which I use as tabs in my toolbar. Is there any possibility of connecting an ImageButton from a fragment in my MainActivity to an other Activity. I know how to connect Activity to Activity through an imagebuttom, i just don't know how to do it from Fragment-> Activity. Thanks.

I have an image button on my fragment, and I want to open an activity when I press that ImageButton.

```
public class Movies extends Fragment {


    public Movies() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    ImageButton imageButton2;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies, container, false);
        imageButton2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

        imageButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intentLoadNewActivity = new Intent(Movies.this, Activity_Civil_War.class);
                startActivity(intentLoadNewActivity);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

I am getting lots of errors. I also tried doing it in the MainActivity but I get the null object exception.

MainActivity Class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
  Toolbar toolbar;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    view_pager_adapter viewPagerAdapter;
    ImageButton imageButton2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById((R.id.toolBar));





        tabLayout=(TabLayout)findViewById((R.id.tabLayout));
        viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById((R.id.ViewPager));
        viewPagerAdapter = new view_pager_adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new Showcase(),"Showcase");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new Movies(),"Movie List");
       viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new Menu(),"Menu");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new Login(),"Login");

        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show what you have done so far ? Code from your fragments. And also be more precise on what you want to achieve, do you want to launch a new Activity from a Fragment ?

Comment: I edited with my code. Yes, i want to launch a new Activity from my Fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things first :

```
 return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies, container, false);
```

If your *return* a value here, the rest of the code below it will not be called. What you need to do is keep a reference to it and return it at the end of your method.

*Then*

```
Intent intentLoadNewActivity = new Intent(Movies.this, Activity_Civil_War.class);
```

I assume that Movies is a Fragment and Activity_Civil_War is an Activity (correct me if I'm wrong).

There is no constructor in the Intent class that takes a Fragment as a parameter. What you are trying to do by calling 'this' is to get a Context. In a Fragment you can do so by calling *getActivity()*

If we sum things up we get :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies, container, false);
    imageButton2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

    imageButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intentLoadNewActivity = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity_Civil_War.class);
            startActivity(intentLoadNewActivity);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```